# Abbreviating commands to make *writing* in (Xe)Latex more painless

Tags: xetex, latex-misc

TLDR; can I shorten commands like \footnote-->\f etc., to reduce code in text?

--

I'm trying to Latex an unobtrusive way to write (academic) Texts in general. (As with many other tools, the problem is that LateX actually geared towards typesetting, but I can't find a better way to write and do bibliography quickly and with high quality and flexibility.) I always end up using LateX, but all the code makes the writing / composing of text itself a bit of a pain. That's offset by the speed and comfort of plain text files, but still...

So now I thought about making some commands more manageable and less intrusive, e.g. by replacing "\footnote{}" with "\f{}", "\footcite{}" with "\fc{}", "\emph" with "\e{}" etc. This should, effectively, shift the code-to-text ratio to a level that makes Latex writing the most minimal way of going about things, with all the export functionality Markdown has, but easier.

However, many of the really short commands are already in use for some special characters etc. As I use Xetex and Unicode input, I don't need those, so can I just patch/redefine these commands that have effectively become obsolete? Or are there risks down the line?

I achieved a shorter version by first patching commands like "\f" to something else and then redefining them to others (MWE). That works for Latex but my Pandoc-to-Word conversion throws an error there (Commands already defined, so I guess the patching to undefine didn't work). Not a deal breaker, but I thought some discussion on this (or suggestions) might be advisable.

I know, this is more discussion than question, so feel free to ignore.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
    @book{Kant1, 
        author={Manu Kant}, 
        title={Critique of Pure Treason}, 
        subtitle={Why are there no pink MandMs},
        address={Chocolvania}, 
        shorthand={A},
        year=2017
    } 

    @book{Kant4, 
    author={Franz Kant}, 
title={Down with pink}, 
subtitle={A heteronormative misogynist manifesto},
address={Reesestown}, 
shorthand={Manifesto},
year=2008
}

        @book{Kant2, 
    author={Franz Kant}, 
    title={Ignore my Brother}, 
    subtitle={Hes an idiot},
    address={Reesestown}, 
    shorthand={Moron},
    year=2018
}   
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


%first setup
    %\let\c\ladidah
    %\let\f\doodledum
    %\let\fc\cookiesmonsters
    %\let\e\bingbong
    %\newcommand{\f}{\footnote}
    %\newcommand{\c}{\cite}
    %\newcommand{\fc}{\footcite}
    %\newcommand{\e}{\emph}

%"safe" version
\newcommand{\F}{\footnote}
\newcommand{\ct}{\cite}
\newcommand{\Fc}{\footcite}
\newcommand{\E}{\emph}

\begin{document}



 The idea\F{And what a smart idea it is... -- cf. \ct{Kant4} as well as \ct{Kant1}.} is to get as little code in the way of \E{text production} as possible.\Fc[2]{Kant2} 

 \end{document}
```

The visual difference (code is colored).
[image]

Comment: Don't do this. Use markdown instead and convert to word and latex with pandoc

Comment: There are two main risks: (a) you have to memorize a number of own aliases and when asking for help you have to revert to ordinary syntax and (b) this is not a good idea for collaboration (which you might or might not want to do). I would suggest to get a decent TeX editor with command completion and you will not need to worry about the length of the input.

Comment: Even if you think you don't need the command you are overwriting (because you can write `č` instead of `\v{c}`) the command might be needed by code you load (for example `biblatex`'s `.lbx` files generally try to be ASCII only, so they use `\v` and friends extensively in some languages, no matter if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) or code you load simply makes assumptions about the macros that you overwrite resulting in weird errors when you use your new macros. That means you need to be extremely careful when you redefine existing command names.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! @DG' - markdown, as far as I figured it out, is too impractical with the amount of footnotes, even with some plugins to ease them. (And too much 'hacking' editors takes away from the ease of editing text files anywhere.)

Comment: @TeXnician - Thanks! I am using TexStudio and Sublime 3 depending on scenario. Collaboration is not an issue, and if needed, a simple search/replace would turn the file back into standard Tex if needed.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for the info on biblatex, that's a consideration since I rely heavily on bib(la)tex. So I redefined stuff to use commands not previously defined (\F \Fc \ct etc.). That should do it. 

Pandoc still throws an error (Error at "source" (line 324, column 17):
unexpected ()
\begin{document}
                ^), but then again, I'll either find a solution or I can search/replace, or if there are less references, just do the normal commands in case I know I need to produce a .docx.